# echo image location does work with image names that have spaces

Tags: php, mysql, image, location, echo

I am using a MySQL database to store image locations with the goal of posting the images to a page. I'm encountering a problem that I can't seem to figure out. If an image is stored in the database with spaces in the title, for instance "image two.jpg" it will not be displayed on the page. An image with the name "imagetwo.jpg" will be displayed. Here is my code:

```
     <?php
        require('db_connect.php');

        $query = ("SELECT * FROM photos");
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        $num = mysql_numrows($result);
        $i=0;
        while ($i<$num) {
            $name = mysql_result($result, $i, 'Name');
            $price = mysql_result($result, $i, 'Price');
            $price = '$'.$price;
            $description = mysql_result($result, $i, 'Description');
            $location = mysql_result($result, $i, 'Location');
            $id = mysql_result($result, $i, 'id');

            echo "<img src=" . $location . "><br>";
            echo $location;
            echo "<br>";
            echo $id;
            $i++;
        }

        ?>
```

The interesting thing is is that the 'location' is stored in my database and recognizes the spaces, and when I echo the $location variable it displays the proper image name. Why would these not be posted?

Thank you!

Comment: *"echo image location does work with image names that have spaces"* -  Then you should consider replacing spaces with underscores, which is what I did for a similar situation.

Comment: @Fred-ii- That's a workaround, but not a real solution. There's nothing wrong with spaces in file names.

Comment: From the PHP Manual on [mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php): This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

Comment: If this is for a new application, please, do not use `mysql_query`.

Comment: Personally, I don't like filenames containing spaces, they cause a lot of headaches. A workaround yes, as well as a possible solution. @JohnKugelman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line:

```
 echo "<img src=" . $location . "><br>";
```

You're not wrapping the file name in quotes, so the browser only sees the first part of the name, before the space.

Change it to

```
 echo "<img src='" . $location . "'><br>";
                ^                 ^        Note single quotes
```

Comment: That was it! Thank you very much. Such a simple fix yet so easy to overlook.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
echo "<img src='" . $location . "'><br>";
```

or

```
echo "<img src="\" . $location . \""><br>";
```